# Export BizTalk orchestration as template

Tags: visual-studio-2010, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have a BizTalk 2010 orchestration which I want to export as a template in Visual Studio 2010, to be used in other BizTalk projects.  The template file is created in \My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ItemTemplates folder.

I have closed and restarted all instances of Visual Studio.  When I try to add a new item to a BizTalk project the new template is not listed.

When I export a C# class though, it works as expected and I can see the new C# template.

Any ideas on what else I need to do to see my new BizTalk Orchestration template?

Answer (score 0):

Try extracting the ODX file from the zip file and putting it in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2010\Developer Tools\BizTalkProjectItems